# How do I explain a package in NPM whining about a dependency not being met when it apparently is?

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, npm-install

I'm sure I'm just doing something stupid but it bothers me to see the following.

> PS C:\Softies\angular2> npm list --depth=0
>   ...
>   +-- @angular/common@2.4.10
>   +-- @angular/compiler@2.4.10
>   +-- @angular/core@2.4.10
>   +-- @angular/forms@2.4.10
>   ...

Then, when I install a [certain package](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=ng2-table) (not important which because the surprising behavior's been evident in numerous other cases too) I get the following error.

> PS C:\Softies\angular2> npm install ng2-table --save
>   ...
>   +-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/common@2.4.10
>   +-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/compiler@2.4.10
>   +-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/core@2.4.10
>   +-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/forms@2.4.10
>   `-- ng2-table@1.3.2
>   ...

Can someone shed some light on what I might be doing wrong, missing or confusing the concept of?

As a remedy I tried reinstalling everything by `npm install`. No errors in red anymore but the message says as follows.

> npm WARN ng2-table@1.3.2 requires a peer of @angular/common@~2.0.0 but none was installed.
>   npm WARN ng2-table@1.3.2 requires a peer of @angular/compiler@~2.0.0 but none was installed.
>   npm WARN ng2-table@1.3.2 requires a peer of @angular/core@~2.0.0 but none was installed.
>   npm WARN ng2-table@1.3.2 requires a peer of @angular/forms@~2.0.0 but none was installed.

Not sure what to make of it at all... Have I not installed Angular properly?! It seems to work when I run the pages so I suspect that the table pulls my leg...

Comment: If you are sure that all of the other dependencies are not making a problem, try deleting node_modules and open cmd as admin and try again.

Comment: @MarioPetrovic Naa, should've said that, sorry. I cleaned up the dir and reinstalled. Same stuff - happens.

Comment: Are warnings not errors, so your App should still work well. Did you check if you have latest `ng2-table` library version?

Comment: @SrAxi Yes, latest version installed. The errors are there, though. It says *UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/common@2.4.10* at the top and *npm ERR! peer dep missing: @angular/common@~2.0.0, required by ng2-table@1.3.2* later... It's like the table demands version **lower than 2.4.10**. Like if it **requires 2.0.0**. Is that reasonable?!

Comment: Its strange that it is showing 2.0.0 dependencie warning for ng2-table 1.3.2. I see in package.json that it says ^2.0.0 peerDependencie. It seems that it shouldnt affect your project: https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-table/issues/373 . Some1 already had same problem

Comment: @MarioPetrovic Interesting. It's apparently not present in my version so it's been either not distributed out yet or retracted (in the version I'm using, which is 1.3.2). Fairly disturbing... You might want to post the comment as a reply so it can be accepted.   :)

Comment: Ok. Glad you can continue with work. But it is disturbing. And also that update was made 4 months ago.

Comment: @AndyJ And also, edit your question name. NPN => NPM :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that it is a problem with distribution to npm.
Even though on git hub it has correct `package.json`:

```
"@angular/common": "^2.0.0",
"@angular/compiler": "^2.0.0",
"@angular/core": "^2.0.0",
"@angular/forms": "^2.0.0"
```

You can continue working, since it is not throwing error, only warning.

There is also an issue on their github:
https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-table/issues/373

You can, for now, watch what happens there.